# Почему загрузка ASP.NET сайта первый раз происходит очень медленно?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Привет всем!

Значит такой сабж... Имеется внутризаводской ASP.NET сайт, который теперь уже крутится на IIS 7.5 и Windows Server 2008 R2. Когда новый пользователь (ну или тот же пользователь с разных браузеров) запрашивает какую-либо страницу сайта, всегда, ее загрузка первый раз происходит очень медленно. От 30 секунд до минуты. После этого загрузка той же самой и любых других страниц происходит достаточно быстро. Раньше сайт крутился на другом сервере с Windows Server 2003 и IIS 6.0. Сервер был слабенький и все как-то просто мирились с этим. А щас сервер хотим поменять и история та же самая. Но это как предисловие...

Случайно вчера выяснил, что медленная загрузка происходит только при создании новой сессии. При удалении куки ASP.NET_SessionId с браузера страница загружается медленно как в первый раз. Я копировал эту куку с одного браузера в другой и загрузка происходила быстро.

Включил трэйс страниц в файле web.config. Из него видно, что при первой загрузки не сама страница занимает столько времени, а что-то другое. Мое предположение, что процесс IIS запускается и инициализируется каждый раз для каждой новой сессии (на самом деле, я это прочитал в нэте).

```
Страница    Событие                     Время от    Дельта с пред.
                                        начала заг  момента
aspx.page   Begin PreInit       
aspx.page   End PreInit                 0,197994    0,197994
aspx.page   Begin Init                  0,198083    0,000089
aspx.page   End Init                    0,287193    0,089110
aspx.page   Begin InitComplete          0,287246    0,000053
aspx.page   End InitComplete            0,287263    0,000017
aspx.page   Begin PreLoad               0,287274    0,000012
aspx.page   End PreLoad                 0,287286    0,000012
aspx.page   Begin Load                  0,287297    0,000012
aspx.page   End Load                    1,069703    0,782406
aspx.page   Begin LoadComplete          1,069754    0,000051
aspx.page   End LoadComplete            1,072090    0,002336
aspx.page   Begin PreRender             1,072120    0,000030
aspx.page   End PreRender               1,093408    0,021288
aspx.page   Begin PreRenderComplete     1,093450    0,000042
aspx.page   End PreRenderComplete       1,135324    0,041874
aspx.page   Begin SaveState             1,160763    0,025439
aspx.page   End SaveState               1,169515    0,008752
aspx.page   Begin SaveStateComplete     1,169543    0,000028
aspx.page   End SaveStateComplete       1,169556    0,000013
aspx.page   Begin Render                1,169568    0,000012
aspx.page   End Render                  1,242033    0,072465
```

Содержимое моего web.config можно посмотреть тут: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8U...5SDA/edit?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Uq0IASkVfMSGNWZzJ1LTg5SDA/edit?usp=sharing) .

IIS настроен на использование .NET Framework 4.0. Версия ASP.NET тоже 4.0. Исходники сайта я пытался прекомпилировать и на время загрузки это не повлияло.

Настройки IIS, если нужно, то покажу. Только не знаю если честно как это сделать и где они хранятся.

Вопрос: что можно сделать, чтобы сайт открывался быстро с первого раза?

Comment: Минута как-то дико. А простые страницы типа "Hello world" также грузятся?

Comment: В таблице время в секундах кстати. Я не сказал. Да, простые тоже. Я говорю, станица грузится приемлемо быстро. Все время, как я понимаю, уходит на старт новой сессии. Так как если использовать какой-либо из старых идентификаторов сессии, то страница будет грузиться быстро везде и у всех. А вот если я удаляю куку, то заставляю ASP.NET принудительно начать новую сессию и это его видимо заставляет задуматься...

Comment: Посмотрите вот эту статью: [Speeding up your application with the IIS Auto-Start feature](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2013/03/05/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/). + Там в комментариях есть еще ссылки на информацию по Application Initialization Module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все. Ларчик просто открывался. Оказывается ASP.NET и IIS были нормально настроены. Все дело было в самом сайте. В Global.asax файле в атрибуте Inherits был прописан класс, который, мягко говоря, и тормозил весь сайт. Класс был написан давно и все уже забыли о его существовании. А, оказывается, там был реализован метод Session_OnStart в котором производилось очень много запросов к базе данных. Потому у меня и грузился долго сайт при создании новой сессии. А я вот переделывал Global.asax, а на эту непримечательную строчку и внимания даже не обратил.

Сначала мы выяснили, что, оказывается, процесс iis по каким-то неведомым нам причинам делал очень много Tcp запросов к серваку с нашей базой Oracle через программу SysInternals ProcMon. А потом через стандартный профайлер для ASP.NET в Visual Studio выяснили какой именно метод занимал больше всего процессорного времени. Надо почаще профилировщиками пользоваться... Сделал я такой вывод для себя.